# Dynamically Created Element Doesn't Respond on Click - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have normal elements where my jQuery code is working as expected.

```
<div class="upperClass">
  <span class="entry" sub-id="1"></span>
  <span class="entry" sub-id="2"></span>
  <span class="entry" sub-id="3"></span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.entry').click(function () {
          console.log("A");
    });
});
```

A gets logged in the console as expected. Then I dynamically create span elements with jQuery and append.

```
<span class="entry" sub-id="4"></span>
<span class="entry" sub-id="5"></span>
```

But dynamically created spans don't log anything.

Comment: Why didn't you close your HTML tags? That could be your problem.

Comment: @King What do you mean? I've close them normally. This is just a snippet code. @MinusFour I am using `click()` rather than `on()`, so I couldn't figure out how to adapt `eventName, selector, function`

Comment: You're missing the `>` at the end of `<span>`

Comment: @Barmar I fixed it. It was just my question being wrong. @MinusFour, I tried `$('.hello').on('click', 'upperClass', function () {` but that works for normals but not dynamically created ones either :/

Comment: Which is the dynamically created element? It should be `$(".upperclass").on("click", ".entry", function() { ...`